# How to get single book details from server using backbone model?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am creating simple book library using backbone.js. Functionalities are very simple.

1.) Get All Books
2.) Get Particular Book (from server)
3.) Display Books

from the collection i can get all the books. But how can I get single book from server using Models ? I need to make ajax call to server to get the book details. since the details may update pretty soon (I don't want to get it from all books collection)

So far I created Views, Model, Collections as follows

```
var Book: Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name: "",
    id: ""
  }
});


var Library: Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book,

  url: function(){
     return "/books";
  },

  fetchBooks: function(){
     fetch({
         success: success_callback,
         error: error_callback
     });
  },

  fetchBook: function(bookId){
     //how to get single book ? 
  }
});
```

How do I get single item from the server using my existing models and collections ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your Model outside the scope of a collection, you need to [specify the urlRoot property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot):

```
var Book: Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: ""
    // ** See Note on Defaults below ...
  },

  urlRoot: "/books"
});
```

After that you can initialize the Model with a given ID and `fetch` it:

```
fetchBook: function(bookId){
  var book = new Book({ id: bookId });
  book.fetch({
      success: function() {
          console.log('Received book: ' + book.toJSON());
      }
  });
}
```

This will result in a `GET` request to `/books/{id}'.  Assuming the server returns JSON, all your results will be populated as attributes on the book instance.

** NOTE on Defaults:  You definitely shouldn't have an `id` default to an empty string, as Backbone uses the presence or absence of an `id` to determine if a model has been saved on the server or not.  For instance if you ever use `model.save(...)`, Backbone will issue a POST if the `id` does not exist, or a PUT if the `id` does exist.